# How do I get rows numbers from a DataFrame based on some equations?

Tags: python

how do i get rows list where condition equals in rows at python?
i'm trying to drop outliers and show to user which rows numbers are dropped in list like:
0,5,21,58 dropped.

```
y= (df[x].loc[df[x] <= low_lim])
        print(y)
        print(type(y))
```

i tried that and get only one value

```
0
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the binary mask and apply it on different rows, you can then check from the mask what rows were dropped. Also, the mask works such that you specify which value you want to keep, not drop, so you have to use `>` instead if you want to drop value below your lower limit:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Randomize data
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)], "y": [random.randint(10, 20) for _ in range(10)]})
low_lim = 5
# Create binary mask
mask = (df["x"] > low_lim)
# Drop rows according to binary mask
df_masked = df[mask]
# Make list from mask row indexes that are False i.e. dropped
dropped = list(mask[mask == False].index)
print(df_masked)
print(dropped)
```

Comment: thank you. it's working :)